# If the sides $a$, $b$ and $c$ of $\triangle ABC$ are in Arithmetic Progression

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, arithmetic-progressions

If the sides $a$, $b$ and $c$ of $\triangle ABC$ are in Arithmetic Progression, then prove that:
$$\cos (\dfrac {B-C}{2})=2\sin (\dfrac {A}{2})$$

My Attempt:

Since, $a,b,c$ are in AP
$$2b=a+c$$
$$\sin A+\sin C=2\sin B$$
$$2\sin (\dfrac {A+C}{2}).\cos (\dfrac {A-C}{2})=2\sin B$$
$$\sin (\dfrac {A+C}{2}).\cos (\dfrac {A-C}{2})=\sin B$$
$$\sin (\dfrac {A+C}{2}).\cos (\dfrac {A-C}{2})=2.\sin (\dfrac {A+C}{2}).\cos (\dfrac {A+C}{2})$$
$$2\cos (\dfrac {A+C}{2})=\cos (\dfrac {A-C}{2})$$

Comment: You are actually very close! Hint: $A+B+C=180^\circ$

Comment: Upon applying Wojowu's hint, you will have proven $$\cos\frac{A-C}{2} = 2\sin\frac{B}{2}$$ which shows that the problem statement is wrong. We should have suspected this: If $a$, $b$, $c$ is an arithmetic progress, then (as you know) $b$ is the arithmetic mean of $a$ and $c$; thus, side $b$ is "special", whereas sides $a$ and $c$ are interchangeable. The same should be true of the opposing angles, so that, if one of them is to appear alone in a relation, it must be $B$. The interchangeability of $A$ and $C$ is reflected in the evenness of cosine, since $$\cos\frac{A-C}{2} = \cos\frac{C-A}{2}$$

Comment: @Blue, so how to get the required proof?

Comment: @blue_eyed_...: If $a$, $b$, $c$ are in arithmetic progression, the correct relation is the one in my previous comment. Use Wojowu's hint to replace $A+C$ on the left-hand side of your last step, and the result reduces to that relation. (I wonder if the problem's original source meant to write "$a$ is the arithmetic mean of $b$ and $c$" (ie, $b+c=2a$), but someone along the way accidentally changed that to "$a$, $b$, $c$ are in arithmetic progression" ($a+c=2b$).)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because it is not true. Consider a right-angle triangle with the sides $3,4,5$. Then:
$$\cos \left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos{(B-C)}}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos B\cos C+\sin B\sin C}{2}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}},\\
2\sin \frac A2=2\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos A}{2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}.$$